# Install `mysql` gem for use in `chef-client`?

Tags: mysql, chef, gem

I am trying to deploy a rails application using chef, for the mysql cookbook to create a database, it needs the `mysql` gem. The `mysql` gem is installed system-wide by using an Ubuntu package, but this is not usable by `chef-client` which runs from `/opt/chef/embedded`.

I have tried adding this:

```
chef_gem 'mysql' do
    action :nothing
end.run_action(:install)
```

But this requires the `libmysqlclient-dev` Ubuntu package to be installed. Therefore I have also added this before the previous:

```
package 'libmysqlclient-dev' do
    action :nothing
end.run_action(:install)
```

But this is done before the `apt` recipe updates the apt repositories, and therefore the install of `libmysqlclient-dev` fails.

These 'hacks' look ugly and I am unable to find a way to run the `apt-get update` at the right time.

Could someone please help me to find the right (the most chef-like) way to solve my problem (the actual problem is to create the database using the `application` cookbook)?

### Update

I have been able to fix the problem with this recipe as an ugly hack... I'm still searching for a better solution:

```
execute "apt-get update" do
  ignore_failure true
  action :nothing
end.run_action(:run)

node.set['build_essential']['compiletime'] = true
include_recipe "build-essential"

%w{build-essential mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev}.each do |p|
  package p do
    action :nothing
  end.run_action(:install)
end

chef_gem 'mysql' do
  action :nothing
end.run_action(:install)
```

Comment: There are some tickets tracking the topic of installing "database" gems (for mysql and postgresql specifically) on tickets.opscode.com, COOK-1441, COOK-1384, COOK-1009.

Answer (score 5):

The `mysql::ruby` recipe allow to install packages via `node["mysql"]["client"]["packages"]`:

Therefore include it in your run list:

```
run_list(
  #...
  "recipe[mysql::ruby]",
  #...
)
```

and specify your dependencies in the attributes:

```
# this is needed for debian based systems
node["mysql"]["client"]["packages"] = ["build-essential","mysql-client","libmysqlclient-dev"]
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a link between the Debian package management system and gem so the answer is probably this:

```
package "libmysqlclient-dev" do
  action :install
end

gem_package "mysql" do
  action :install
end
```

(The `chef_gem` resource does install a gem, but it's only for installing gems to use inside a Chef recipe.  See all the gory details at the [Chef Resources page](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Resources)).

For keeping apt under control, I recommend using the [apt Opscode community cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/apt) and add `recipe[apt]` to the beginning of the run list for all nodes.

Comment: I am using `chef_gem` on purpose, as I already wrote the `mysql` gem has already been installed in the system... It can't be used by `chef-client` so I need to install it with `chef_gem`...